# I2C & SPI Power On Self test

Tags: c, boot, i2c, spi, diagnostics

I am currently working on boot time diagnostic software for Beagle Board - xm it is just like POST ( power on self test ) what we have in BIOS systems , So as we know during early stage there is no driver present so that i came to know that i have to write a basic low level driver for the peripherals, but my question is what kind of test should be performed in boot time whether it is limited to basic read/write ( in case of my devices like i2c & spi) or i need to perform test for each and every functionality of the peripherals. So i just want to know what kind of tests are conducted or what kind of steps are followed for I2c & SPI during a boot time diagnosis .

Comment: Will your firmware boot up another kernel with full driver support? Then why bother? Just make sure the flash and RAM is okay and let the OS handle the peripherals.

Comment: This is the third question you ask on exactly the same topic. It would have been better to edit your original question. Certainly, it would make sense for you to delete the other questions now.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg ! Sir you are right kernel will have all driver support but what if i want to check before kernel appears just like a POST in BIOS.

Comment: @unixsmurf I deleted other question and now this the only question alive !

Answer (score 0):

Usually devices like I2C and SPI have default values of some registers according to their documentations. At boot time you can read from your diagnostic procedure all I2C/SPI peripheral devices and check obtained data. If you can read  (default for reset or even better - read only constants) and determine they are correct, that means these parts are OK at this stage.

Comment: Thanks for answer !!!!!!!!! But Whatever default values you are saying is it related to slave i2c/spi devices , what if i need to check working of master or i2c/spi controllers present on SOC. Whether reading & writing to a slave device from controller do the job of boot time diagnostic or we need to check other functionalities  also.